# Breeze.js One to One Relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, breeze

I have a one to one Relationship in EF.

```
public partial class ttQuestion
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual ttCategory ttCategory { get; set; }
}

public partial class ttCategory
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query it with breeze.js but ttCategory is not serialized to json. I think i have set the keys wrong? I also tried to set the ttCategory.ID as ForeignKey without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that i have to call the expand method from breeze.js to eager load the categories